# Using Zend_Db_Expr with Zend Framework 2.2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Is it Possible that I use Zend_Db_Expr class in zend framework version 2.2 for making subqueries, if not what are the alternatives?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of : [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183061/zf2-zend-db-insert-update-using-mysql-expression-zend-db-sql-expression)

Check if `vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Sql\Expression.php`
is like Zf1 version.